# Equivalence of Definitions of Independence for Random Variable and $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I am trying to establish the equivalence between two definitions of the independence of a random variable $X$ from a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$.

**Definition 1:** For all events $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \mathcal F$,
$ P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) $.

**Definition 2:** For any continuous and bounded function $F$,
$ \mathbb{E}[F(X)\mid \mathcal F] = \mathbb{E}[F(X)] $

I am interested in showing that Definition 1 implies Definition 2 and vice-versa.

**Attempts**

I believe that this may be tackled by studying first the simpler case of indicator functions. Taking a set $B \in \mathcal F$, I considered $I_B(X)$, which is $1$ if $X \in B$ and $0$ otherwise.  But I am struggling to even set this problem up, as I don’t know how to compute the conditional expectation of the indicator function that $X$ is in $B$ given $\mathcal F$.

**Postscript**

This is what I need for a problem, but I’m not sure at all if it’s right.

Comment: It might help to start with writing out the definition of $\mathbb{E}[F(X)|\mathcal F]$, i.e. what does it mean for $\mathbb{E}[F(X)|\mathcal F] = \mathbb{E}[F(X)]$?

Comment: Sorry, had made a mistake. The definition of conditional expectation is through the defining relation, i.e. the conditional expectation is a measurable RV wrt to $\mathcal{F}$ such that for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ we have that
$$
\int_A E[F(X) \mid \mathcal{F}] d \mathbb{P}=\int_A F(X)d \mathbb{P} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, we will first show this is true for indicator functions.

First, suppose $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ for all $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B \in \mathcal F$.  Then, observe that if $a < b $, $E[I_{(a,b)}(X)] = P(X \in (a,b))$ and $\{X \in (a,b)\} \in \sigma(X)$, so for any $B \in \mathcal F$ we have
\begin{align*}
\int_B \mathbb{E}[I_{(a,b)}(X)] d\mathbb{P} &= \mathbb{P}(X \in (a,b)) \int_B d \mathbb{P} \\
&= \mathbb{P}(X \in (a,b)) \mathbb{P}(B) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(\{X \in (a,b)\} \cap B) \tag{By definition 1} \\
&= \int_B I_{(a,b)}(X) d \mathbb{P},
\end{align*}
so $\mathbb{E}[I_{(a,b)}(X)|\mathcal F] = \mathbb{E}[I_{(a,b)}(X)]$.  The converse direction works exactly the same way.

We extend to step functions by linearity, then extend to continuous bounded functions by taking a limit of step functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which largely makes sense to me. Could you please elaborate a little bit about how to take the limit of step functions and get continuous bounded functions?

Comment: @MartinGeller A continuous bounded function $f$ is the pointwise limit of step functions, and since $f$ is bounded the dominated convergence theorem lets us interchange the limit and expected value.  Does that clarify it, or should I elaborate more on either part of that?